# Use jsp by action button

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

i don't know why this code don't work correctly. I want print "AAAAA" only when i click in the button, but if i launch this and i click in the button, don't change nothing and the string is every time printed. Why don't work?

```
<html>
  <head>
   <link rel="stylesheet"href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
        </head>
        <body>

<%
    if(request.getParameter("buttonName") != null) {
           out.println("AAAAAA");
    }
%>

<FORM NAME="form1" METHOD="POST">
    <INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="buttonName">
    <INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE="Button 1" ONCLICK="button1()">
</FORM>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">

    function button1()
    {
        document.form1.buttonName.value = "yes";
        form1.submit();
    }

</SCRIPT>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your js code seems ok . what doesn't work?